# Parsing a chemical formula with Swift

Tags: swift, parsing

I'm new to coding and have been teaching myself through trial and error. I've been working on an app to calculate the molar mass of a chemical compound and cannot seem to get the parentheses to work correctly. For example, Mg(NO3)2 returns the mass with two Mg atoms instead of one. I'm hoping the problem is obvious to someone, because I've been working on it for days now. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
func calculateMolarMass() {
        var totalMass = 0.0
        var i = compoundFormula.startIndex
        var massStack: [Double] = []
        var operatorStack: [Character] = []
        var openParenthesesCount = 0
        var openSquareBracketsCount = 0
        
        while i < compoundFormula.endIndex {
            let char = compoundFormula[i]
            
            if char.isLetter {
                var elementSymbol = String(char)
                i = compoundFormula.index(after: i)
                
                while i < compoundFormula.endIndex && compoundFormula[i].isLowercase {
                    elementSymbol.append(compoundFormula[i])
                    i = compoundFormula.index(after: i)
                }
                
                var subscriptValue = ""
                while i < compoundFormula.endIndex && compoundFormula[i].isNumber {
                    subscriptValue.append(compoundFormula[i])
                    i = compoundFormula.index(after: i)
                }
                
                let elementMass = atomicMasses[elementSymbol] ?? 0.0
                let multiplier = Double(subscriptValue) ?? 1.0
                
                totalMass += elementMass * multiplier
                
            } else if char == "(" || char == "[" {
                        operatorStack.append(char)
                        i = compoundFormula.index(after: i)

                        if char == "(" {
                            openParenthesesCount += 1
                        } else {
                            openSquareBracketsCount += 1
                        }

                    } else if char == ")" || char == "]" {
                        let openBracket: Character = char == ")" ? "(" : "["
                        i = compoundFormula.index(after: i)

                        while !operatorStack.isEmpty && operatorStack.last != openBracket {
                            applyOperator(&totalMass, &massStack, operatorStack.removeLast())
                        }

                        if operatorStack.isEmpty || operatorStack.last != openBracket {
                            fatalError("Mismatched parentheses/brackets")
                        }

                        if char == ")" {
                            openParenthesesCount -= 1
                        } else {
                            openSquareBracketsCount -= 1
                        }

                        operatorStack.removeLast() // Remove the open parenthesis

                        if i < compoundFormula.endIndex && compoundFormula[i].isNumber {
                            var numberString = ""
                            while i < compoundFormula.endIndex && compoundFormula[i].isNumber {
                                numberString.append(compoundFormula[i])
                                i = compoundFormula.index(after: i)
                            }
                            let multiplier = Double(numberString) ?? 1.0
                            totalMass *= multiplier
                        }
                    }

                    if openParenthesesCount < 0 || openSquareBracketsCount < 0 {
                        fatalError("Mismatched parentheses/brackets")
                    }
                }

                while !operatorStack.isEmpty {
                    if operatorStack.last == "(" || operatorStack.last == "[" {
                        fatalError("Mismatched parentheses/brackets")
                    }
                    applyOperator(&totalMass, &massStack, operatorStack.removeLast())
                }

                if openParenthesesCount != 0 || openSquareBracketsCount != 0 {
                    fatalError("Mismatched parentheses/brackets")
                }

                molarMass = totalMass
            } // Code for calculating Molar Mass
```

Comment: You should look into Regular Expressions

Comment: Thanks! I found this page on your recommendation that looks helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions. I'll do some more reading - I've also seen information of regex that looks helpful.

Comment: There are a couple of videos on the "Developer" App on the new "Regex" it is a user friendly start to it.

Comment: Here is an approach in Python, maybe it is helpful: https://github.com/cgohlke/molmass/blob/master/molmass/molmass.py